# My gnome terminal keep opening new window

Tags: gnome-terminal

I actually want to change the default window position of **gnome-terminal** in my Ubuntu 12.04 system.

After some search, I found some one else use the command `gnome-terminal --geometry=120x80+50+50` to set the default position.

And I actually don't know where to paste the command, so I pasted it to 'custome command' field of terminal's profile.

Now when I open one terminal, it just keep opening new ones and I have no way to stop it other than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I even removed  `.gconf/gnome-termial/` folder and it didn't worked.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Remove the folder actually works, but I have to logout and login again.

Comment: You should probably [create a new launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand).

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to reset gnome-terminal,

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal
```

Or

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>,to enter into virtual console and run the below commands to reinstall `gnome-terminal`.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Not sure that reinstalling gnome-terminal will work, the configuration options are kept in the home dir. The first suggestion should suffice.